# How do I diagnose the yelllow triangle symbol over my battery on Windows 11?

Tags: battery, lenovo-laptop, windows-11

I've got a Lenovo X1 Extreme Gen 3 and, even when using the official chargers, I always get this warning triangle over the battery logo.  I've updated drivers and Windows is up to date.  Even tried the Lenovo support but they're not being any help.  Is there a log somewhere that can tell me why this is flagging up?

[image: Issue]

Comment: You might run battery diagnostics, per https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-check-your-laptops-battery-health-in-windows-10

Comment: Thanks, have run that and nothing looks out of the ordinary.

Comment: You might search the Event Log, e.g., with Nirsoft's FullEventLogView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html , for events logged after plugging and unplugging the charger (that tool lets you search all logs by time). Also, if Lenovo has a battery charge limiter (keeping batteries partially charged prolongs service life), use the GUI to set charge limit.

Comment: Also what do you see when you click on detailed info (in your screen shot). I have 2 machines here on Lenovo Threshold (80%) but that does not cause a yellow warning.  It should show battery health numbers..